# Jquery 1.9.1 datepicker set date option

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a problem when I want to set datepicker set date option on some event, So on event I call this snipped of code:

```
function resetDate() {
 $('#agreementEndDate').datepicker("option", "setDate", new Date());
}
```

And on start of my page I call this:

```
function createAndInitializeToChoosenDate() {
    $('#agreementEndDate').datepicker({dateFormat : "dd.mm.yy"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```

So when I chose on datepicker some date and after that, for example I click button then I go to resetDate() but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) is not an option, it is a method

it should be

```
$('#agreementEndDate').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```